# How can I get the length of a vector in a function whose argument is that vector in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

With the code below,

`function transpose(v) { return v.length; }`

I get the message

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

can somebody kindly let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information about `vector` of `length of a vector` in your question? And from the error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, how do you run the function of `transpose`? For example, `function transpose(v) { return v && v.length; }` is the direction you expect?

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I wanted.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function transpose(v) { return v && v.length; }
```